# How can I search questions with close votes?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, vote-count

I have over 250 reputation points on a few Stack Exchange sites, and I was wondering is there a way to search just in questions that have closed votes.

Or even a page like /closing (it can be re-named) and the 250+ users can see how many votes there are.

Comment: What do you need it for? Can't think of any real use of such feature..

Comment: @Shadow I just want to find more about it.

Comment: more about what? Still don't get you.

Comment: There's no badge to be earned by using all of your close votes or closing a bunch of questions. Consequently, there's absolutely no need for this feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing close votes, AFAIK, is part of the 10K and/or Mod toolkit. Users with less than 10k reputation can still see closed questions but as they aren't tagged as "closed" it's not that easy to categorize them. It might be possible to create something using the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: ... but as the data explorer is up to a month behind, this probably won't help even if it's possible `:-(`

Comment: `but as they aren't tagged as "closed" it's not that easy to catergorise them` -> search with `closed:1` will bring up list of closed questions.