# Why can't I permalink to this Data Explorer query?

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

Why does [this Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2002/stack-overflow-questions-with-outstanding-close-votes) explode (on Firefox 7.0.1, Mac OS X 10.6.8)?

---

[image: Exploding query]

---

I can run the query once, when I compose it for the first time, but all further attempts to access it from my profile or a permalink result in the JSON (?) dump above.

---

[image: Working query]

---

Any ideas?

Comment: Just curious, what's the point of this query?

Comment: @PopularDemand I wrote this query as a response to a question that was asking for a way to search on close votes. Now that I have the query, I can't seem to find the question it was originally intended for...

Comment: I thought that might be it, but I didn't want to assume. Your results will be out of date (at least most of the time) because SEDE runs queries against a monthly data dump. Was [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28391/131713) the one you were thinking of?

Comment: @PopularDemand No, it had more recent activity than that. I think it  was actually a complaint about being unable to find "failed" (i.e. expired) close votes. I agree that the results will be out of date, but they should still be sufficient to find votes that have been languishing in the system for a while.

Comment: [How can I search questions with close votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81320/how-can-i-search-questions-with-close-votes)? [Highlight questions with outstanding close votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86253/highlight-questions-with-outstanding-close-votes)?

Comment: @PopularDemand Ah, [here's the question I was looking at](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83006). It had a +500 rep bounty from Pekka.

Comment: marking this as complete, let me know if it is still a problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the titles in the cached results is

```
Removing <script></script> block from returned html in C#
```

which causes the browser to prematurely terminate the surrounding `</script>` block. The JSON is supposed to have the `/` escaped specifically to avoid this, but I think some refactoring may have interferred with that for cached results that are loaded into the page directly.

I'll see what I can do about a quick-fix.